# Calculate driving directions using PHP?

Tags: php, scripting, google-maps, server-side, driving-directions

For my application I need a server to calculate driving directions.

The [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) was designed for clientside use only, with a Javascript and Flash API. Is there any way I can run their API's server-side?

Comment: Hi, 
  Does it have to be Google Maps, or could you use Bing Maps instead? If the latter, you could check the Bing Maps SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/) as it provides a SOAP webservice, which I presume can be called from a server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps HTTP API for driving and walking directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041601/google-maps-http-api-for-driving-and-walking-directions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know it this isn't official and google doesn't support it but it works:

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', "http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?client=yourclient&output=json&q=from: ".$lat1.",".$lon1." to: ".$lat2.",".$lon2);

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode(utf8_encode($result), true);
```

And you'll have directions in $data array.

Comment: I forgot to say to edit client to suite your needs or replace it with api key

Comment: That URL was never a supported API, just parts of Google Maps site. The correct way is to use the Directions API (not available at the time this answer was posted): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro