# Google Maps HTTP API for driving and walking directions

Tags: google-maps, kml, driving-directions

Do you know how I can get walking directions from Google by giving two specific coordinates?
How can I send simple HTTP GET requests and have the result in a KML file?

I don't want to geocode, but get the driving directions as the KML file returned by this method:

http://www.gringod.com/2008/02/26/save-google-maps-driving-directions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no documented and approved method at the moment to access the Google Maps Directions API via an HTTP request (**update**: Google added walking and driving [directions via web services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) in May, 2010).

Nevertheless, an undocumented method that returns a JSON output is the following:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover
```

The format of the `q` parameter should be `from:xxx%20to:yyy`. Replace xxx and yyy with the start and destination respectively. You can use a latitude and a longitude instead of full addresses.

By default this request returns driving directions. To get walking directions you can add the optional parameter `dirflg=w` to the query-string. ([Source](http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20080812105450589))

Note that not only this is undocumented, but it may also violate the restrictions 10.1 and 10.5 of the [Google Maps API Terms and Conditions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

You may also be interesting in checking out the following articles:

- [Getting distance using GDirections via URL](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/af1dd5cbeaccf32d)
- [Calculate driving directions using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800510/)
- [Retrieve driving directions from google maps with server-side HTTP calls and show results with static maps for WAP](http://mufumbo.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/server-side-driving-direction-with-google-maps-api-with-php-for-wap-and-web/)
- [Google Maps and Directions, REST Interface?](http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20080812105450589)

Answer (score 3):

Google added directions via web services in May, 2010:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Directions are returned in either XML or JSON format.

They also have geocoding, elevation, and places available.