# Converting JSON to KML

Tags: json, google-maps, kml

Do you know how can I convert a google walking directions JSON response to KML?

I am using this method to get driving directions from Google in JSON format:

- [Google Maps HTTP API for driving and walking directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041601/google-maps-http-api-for-driving-and-walking-directions)

How can I process this and export it to KML to view it on Google Earth? Is there a Java API or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will be able to tackle this conversion as follows:

1. You can parse the JSON data from Google using the [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).
2. Then to export the KML, you may want to use [JAK - Java API for KML](http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home). You can also try to do this manually by following the [Google KML Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert json file to kml as following

ogr2ogr -f KML /Users/Me/Documents/mydata.kml /Users/Me/Documents/mydata.json

You can also do the same from a python script:

import subprocess
subprocess.call("ogr2ogr -f KML /Users/Me/Documents/mydata.kml /Users/Me/Documents/mydata.json",shell=True)

Comment: you really should consider improving your answer... but thanks anyway for pointing me to qgis! 