# Using PHP and google Maps Api to work out distance between 2 post codes (UK)

Tags: php, google-maps

Hay, I wondering how to work out distance between 2 post codes using PHP and Google Maps Api.

Any one got any idea or links to examples.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the [geographic distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance), first you need to get the latitude and longitude of your two postcodes with the [Google Maps server-side geocoding services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) as in the following example:

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=EC3M,+UK&output=csv&sensor=false';

$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$result = explode(",", $data);

echo $result[0]; // status code
echo $result[1]; // accuracy
echo $result[2]; // latitude
echo $result[3]; // longitude
```

Then you can calculate the distance between the coordinates of your two postcodes by using a [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) implementation such as the following:

- [Snipplr - Calculate distance between two coordinates in PHP](http://snipplr.com/view/2531/calculate-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-latitude-longitude/)

Note that the server-side geocoding service may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited by the [Google Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).

---

**UPDATE:**

If you are looking for the driving distance instead of the geographical distance, note that there is no documented and approved method at the moment to access the Google Maps Directions API via an HTTP request on the server-side.

Nevertheless, an undocumented method that returns a JSON output is the following:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover
```

This will return you the driving directions, along with the total driving distance in JSON format: `"meters":122977`.

The format of the `q` parameter should be `from:xxx%20to:yyy`. Replace xxx and yyy with the start and destination respectively. You can use latitude and a longitude coordinates instead of full addresses:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:51.519894,-0.105667%20to:51.129079,1.306925
```

Note that not only this is undocumented, but it may also violate the restrictions 10.1 and 10.5 of the [Google Maps API Terms and Conditions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

You may also be interesting in checking out the following related articles:

- [Stack Overflow: Calculate driving directions using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800510/)
- [Getting distance using GDirections via URL](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/af1dd5cbeaccf32d)
- [Retrieve driving directions from google maps with server-side HTTP calls and show results with static maps for WAP](http://mufumbo.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/server-side-driving-direction-with-google-maps-api-with-php-for-wap-and-web/)
- [Google Maps and Directions, REST Interface?](http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20080812105450589)

Comment: This is a great explanation of how to do it. But be aware, since you are asking specifically about the UK, that the Google geolocation isn't that accurate for UK postcodes. It might be OK for your purposes though, depends what you need.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for sharing this info on the accuracy of UK postcodes.

Comment: driving distance does appear to be officially documented here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

edit: actually i noticed they havent used a php example

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if the V3 API changes anything, but I've been using this for quite a while and it still works:

From and to are each expressed as latitude,longitude (an address would probably work;
I'm sure I tried it but don't remember and I had the coordinates anyway)

```
$base_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$base_url&origin=$from&destination=$to");
$distance = (string)$xml->route->leg->distance->text;
$duration = (string)$xml->route->leg->duration->text
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Daniel's answer, you can use Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?csw=1) to get car, public transport, walking and cycling distances easily :

```
$postcode1='W1J0DB';
$postcode2='W23UW';
$result = array();

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$postcode1&destinations=$postcode2&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$result = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($result);
```

Be sure to replace *&mode=bicycling* with your preferred parameter:

- &mode=driving
- &mode=bicycling
- &mode=transit
- &mode=walking

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I got it to work in 2022:**

```
$postcode1 = '78211';
$postcode2 = '78355';
$commute_mode = 'driving';
$api_key = 'YOUR-KEY-HERE';
$result = array();

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=$api_key&origins=$postcode1&destinations=$postcode2&mode=$commute_mode&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$result = json_decode($data, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Make sure to get your [Google Maps API](https://maps.googleapis.com) and replace the text `YOUR-KEY-HERE` with your actual API Key and change the other parameters as you see fit. Google gives you free maploads every month upto a value of $200, so you can integrate Google Maps API easily and test the same to see if it fits your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API is in JavaScript, not PHP. To achive what you want, turn the 2 post codes to LatLang coordinates and use the function `distanceFrom` to find the distance between them.

Comment: Is there anyway i can return JSON data? I going to be doing AJAX calls to work out driving distance between 2 places.

Comment: You should be able to. Data coming from the Google API is already in JSON form. Just sent it back to PHP, or parse it client-side using Javascript.