# Using PHP and google Maps Api to work out distance between 2 latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

Just wondering how to work out distance between 2 latitude and longitude using PHP and Google Maps Api.

Any one got any idea or links to examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296087/using-php-and-google-maps-api-to-work-out-distance-between-2-post-codes-uk Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

I think you might be after something like this which has a few good answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcDistance($lat1,$Lang1, $lat2, $Lang2)
{
    //RAD
    $b1 = ($lat1/180)*M_PI;
    $b2 = ($lat2/180)*M_PI;
    $l1 = ($Lang1/180)*M_PI;
    $l2 = ($Lang2/180)*M_PI;
    //equatorial radius
    $r = 6378.137;
    // Formel
    $e = acos( sin($b1)*sin($b2) + cos($b1)*cos($b2)*cos($l2-$l1) );
    return round($r*$e, 4);
}
```