# Best way to calculate distance between two Postcodes (UK)?

Tags: javascript, html, maps, distance

What method do you recommend I use to calculate the distance between two UK postcodes to decide whether it is in range or not?

I will not be displaying a map, simply showing a list of results of valid locations. e.g. Locations within 50 miles of BT53 6EX

Comment: Already answered here (PHP) amigo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296087/using-php-and-google-maps-api-to-work-out-distance-between-2-post-codes-uk and here's the JS equivalent: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints?csw=1

Comment: "Note that the server-side geocoding service may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map" I will not be displaying a map

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://bit.ly/1Q7jVtv

Comment: @Barett you're the least helpful person I've ever had answer one of my questions. I hope to never receive any replies from you on any of my posts ever again. Thanks

Comment: Did you try visiting any of the links? 2 are free api's to do exactly what you're looking for. http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api . http://postcodes.io mentioned below is another good one.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, you don't really specify anything to answer you question in a satisfactory way.

Store latitude and longitude along postcodes and filter so that latitude AND longitude difference is within 50 miles:

```
SELECT * FROM postcodes WHERE ABS(latitude - @lat) < 50 AND ABS(longitude - @lng) < 50
```

Then filter the resulting set by computing the actual distance, because the query above would return all in a square 50 miles distance, not in a radial distance.

Comment: How would I convert the postcodes I have into geographical distance?

Comment: @EnayetHussain Ha! I supposed wrongly that you already have that data. I downloaded similar data from the Ministry of Internal Affairs (in Italy) for a system that required it (but only distances between cities). Maybe there's a database that has all that data. But as Tim suggests, that API may be way way better! listen to him please :)