# How do I calculate total distance from Point A to point B along a certain path using PHP & the google API?

Tags: php, google-api

I need to calculate the total distance traveled from a location to a destination.

However, it's not as simple as the distance between two points. I need to calculate the total distance along a certain path, so I'll have a few other locations that must be visited before I arrive at the destination.

Is this possible via PHP, I've done it in JS but my PHP background is not as strong...

Comment: does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296087/using-php-and-google-maps-api-to-work-out-distance-between-2-post-codes-uk

Comment: haversine formula is what you need. check this SO post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but eventually lead me to my solution... I'll post it bellow.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up looking more into the issue. It seems there's no straight API that will solely calculate the distance between multiple points...

However, with a little bit of effort we are able to calculate the distance traveled using this API...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Essentially we want to get a route (index 0 should be fine) we then want to iterate over each of it's legs and add each legs distance.value to a total sum. The result is the distance of all destinations...

Only downside, you also get a bunch of unnecessary information as this API is meant for giving directions.