# Tips for setting up a public transportation route planner

Tags: google-maps, architecture, schema, gtfs

I am intending to develop in the near future a web app for planning a route using my local public transportation system. I will be using Google Maps and I would like to hear some tips on how should I start planning this project for maximum efficiency (how should I store the stations, lines, times for each line, common stations etc, and also how to draw a route following roads - not just a straight line between two points). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Public Transportation in Metropolitan Areas you can use the google maps api

[How to get Google Maps Public Transit Directions by HTTP server-side request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689542/how-to-get-google-maps-public-transit-directions-by-http-server-side-request)

Comment: Since this Google service is unavailable in my country, I need to map all stations and then generate the desired routes.

Comment: Using the method described in that post may violate Maps Terms of use, and is undocumented and therefore not guaranteed to be around.

Answer (score 0):

There's a defacto standard way to encode and interchange transit data. Lots of transit agencies are releasing their data in [Google Transit Feed Spec](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html) format. You might check to see if your agency has already done so. There are also open source tools for dealing with GTFS. For instance: http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/

Comment: My agency is far from doing so, far even from informing its clients when do the trams/buses arrive at each station. That's the many reason I intend to develop this app. I don't want to do their "job" (i.e. submitting all that info on the link you posted); I simply wish to make my own database, only with stations, lines, and some arriving times which I'll get by using some sort of algorithm. I wanted only to know what's the best way to organize my data (I'll be using MySQL), and how would I "draw" the route a user requests between two points (mainly, how to draw a line which follows a road).