# How to use Bing Map API in iOS application to draw route between two location?

Tags: ios, bing-maps, bing-api

I want to use `Bing Map API` in my `iOS` application two show map view and to draw route between two location. I am not getting proper link and sample tutorial for `Bing map API`. Please help  me out.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of link you do not get? to the tutorial? btw why Bing? I have used MapQuest once, worked nicely in my case

Comment: I have another option to use google API. But we want to use Bing because it is free to use.

Comment: okay, but could you clarify what do you want as it is not clear. I wish to help you but I do not understand what do you want :)

Comment: simply I want use Bing map library in my application. So that i will use methods of that library and show mapView. then will show route between two location.

Comment: okay, so where is the problem? in documentation or where?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx Have you seen this?

Comment: Conversation already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264448/how-can-i-draw-specify-a-route-on-a-dynamic-bing-map-using-the-bing-maps-ios-sd

Comment: Worth noting that Bing Maps is not free to us. It does have free terms of use with a limit of 50,000 transactions a day for mobile app (twice what Google offers)

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps no longer offers an iOS map control, however most developers who use Bing Maps in an iOS application use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control. It works great in iOS. Simply embed it inside of a WebBrowser control inside of your app.

Comment: Here are some blog posts on doing this: 

http://www.soulsolutions.com.au/Blog.aspx?Search=phonegap%20maps&SearchType=Keyword


http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap.aspx